# get current app running android (app blocker)

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app in android that can block other apps on a specific time. I have found several questions on stackoverflow talking about this, but the solutions they provide are deprecated and nowadays not working. I am actually a little bit lost, so any ideas would be appreciated. The steps are (for the moment):

1. List all installed apps.
2. Detect the name of the app that is currently running (in a service).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers to your question.

> 1. List all installed apps.

```
PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

> 2. Detect the name of the app that is currently running (in a service).

There is currently no way to detect or get info on the currently running apps or services. This was depricated long ago because of security reasons.

## getRunningTasks

#### `public List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> getRunningTasks (int maxNum)`

> This method was deprecated in API level 21.
>   As of Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party applications: **the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person information to the caller**. For backwards compatibility, it will still return a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks, and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be sensitive.
>
> **Note: this method is only intended for debugging and presenting task management user interfaces.** This should never be used for core logic in an application, such as deciding between different behaviors based on the information found here. Such uses are not supported, and will likely break in the future. For example, if multiple applications can be actively running at the same time, assumptions made about the meaning of the data here for purposes of control flow will be incorrect.

[Check it here for more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int))

Hope this helps.

Comment: so, what I am trying to build is impossible in API>21, right? Thanks.